# Magento 2 Remove page-wrapper from Magento/blank theme

Tags: layout, magento-2.1, theme

I am developing a new theme for Magento 2, based on Magento/blank.
I am trying to remove the div "page-wrapper", unsuccessfully.
Inside my `app/design/frontend/custom/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` I inserted the following `<referenceContainer name="page_wrapper" remove="true"/>` but nothing happens, the div is still there. What should I do to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the block name.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: I tried your way, but the div is still there

Comment: That's weird, I just tried it myself. Have you cleared the cache? Can you post the whole xml?

Comment: It works, I made a typo error. I named the xml deafult instead of default :(

Comment: yee! good work :)

Comment: here only worked with name="header.panel.wrapper"